# Want to select first row from table when the page loads using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to select first row when the page loads in my application. Currently, When I click on row then the row is getting selected but I want the row to be selected on page load. The same code is working in demo project but not into my application. I do not know where I am getting wrong. Please help me.

```
//Style

   tr.highlight td {
        background: #FFA07A;
    }

//My JavaScript Code:

  $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#tblData tr").click(function (e) {
                $("#tblData tr").removeClass("highlight");
                $(this).addClass("highlight");
            });
           var firstTr = $('#tblData tr:first');
           firstTr.addClass('highlight');        
        });
```

Comment: `$("#tblData tr").click(function (e) {}).click();` click programmatically so on load it calls it

Comment: if you log firstTr to the console, do you get an element?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can you please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working in this snippet with your code and html I suppose you are using:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tblData tr").click(function (e) {
    $("#tblData tr").removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
  });
  var firstTr = $('#tblData tr:first');
  firstTr.addClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
tr.highlight td {
   background: #FFA07A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblData">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, this code works in separate project but not into this. I do not get any error either.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean the code I pasted in the question is working if I create a separate project and put it there but does not work in my current project. The click event is working properly but on load.

Comment: If you feel that this question is useful to future readers then please up vote this. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I want to suggest 2 simple solutions for you

Solution 1

```
//Style
tr.highlight td: {
    background: #FFA07A;
}
tr.highlight:first-child td{
    background: #FFA07A;
}
```

Solution 2 check the first row in view

```
$first_row = 0;
foreach($data as $row){
  $first_row++;
  $hight_light = $first_row == 1 ? "highlight" : "";
  echo '<tr class="'.$hight_light .'">
   <td>
   </td>
  </tr>';
}
```